# Produce reports using data from two different types of database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, db2, report, data-migration

I have data on SQL Server 2008 and DB2 10.1.  I want to compare the data in some of the tables across both databases and produce reports showing things like if the data in the records match/mismatches, how many records match etc.

Problems are that they are in two different types of database and the data is store in tables and columns with different names and possibly data types too.

I just wanted to know if anyone had any recommendations on the best way to do this with the tools I've got (SQL Server 2008 and DB2 10.1) or whether any inexpensive tools that could be used?

Thanks

Comment: Not ideal of course, but you could dump the data to a file and use a standard file compare tool (WinMerge etc).

Comment: Don't know what your criteria for "best" are, but both MS SQL Server Integration Services and IBM InfoSphere Federation Server should be able to handle that task.

Comment: Alternatively, if your C#/VB.NET foo was up to it, you could easily roll your own.